# Stored function that will check 2 attributes of the PostgreSQL database and then verify to save it in database

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to create a PostgreSQL function(stored procedure) to verify in my database if `idnum` and `myear` are already present. Example: `idnum=111` and `myear=2015`. If the `idnum` does not exist it will automatically `INSERT` the `idnum` and `myear` in the database. If the `idnum` exists and the corresponding `myear` doesn't, it will also save in the database. But if the `idnum` and `myear` both are already exist it will update the database. Here is my sample function code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pl_bryan(mid integer, mmyear integer)
RETURNS SETOF bryans AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  hh_num integer;
  hh_yr integer;
BEGIN  
  hh_num := (SELECT idnum FROM bryans WHERE idnum=$1);
  hh_yr := (SELECT myear FROM bryans WHERE myear=$2);

  IF hh_num IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO bryans(idnum,myear) VALUES ($1,$2); 
  ELSIF hh_num IS NOT NULL AND hh_yr IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO bryans(idnum,myear) VALUES ($1,$2);   
  ELSE

  END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you want to `RETURN` from your function, so I'll leave that out here. The solution to your stated question would be like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pl_bryan (mid integer, mmyear integer) RETURNS VOID AS $BODY$
BEGIN  
  PERFORM * FROM bryans WHERE idnum = mid AND myear = mmyear;
  IF FOUND THEN
    -- Both values found in one record, so do the UPDATE, unclear how you want that done
  ELSE
    -- The combination is not found, so INSERT it
    INSERT INTO bryans (idnum, myear) VALUES (mid, mmyear); 
  END;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Hi James. If this answers your question, you should accept the answer: tick grey check mark below the voting buttons on the left. This is how proper answers to questions are identified on SO. Good luck with PostgreSQL!